# how to open a web page on click of button in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, installscript

HI,

I want to open a web page on click of a button in any dialog that is created in InstallShield. I think it can be created by using custom actions but as I am new in this tool do not find the exact way to achieve this. Please help if anyone have idea for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like epotter mentioned, you could do the following

To open a local html file

```
LaunchAppAndWait( "explorer.exe", "c:\temp\readme.html", WAIT );
```

or to open a remote site

```
LaunchAppAndWait( "explorer.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", WAIT );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the handler code for the button press, call LaunchApplication. Pass in the full path to the browser of your choice and the URL to which you want to navigate.